# Using Count in sql

Tags: mysql

I need help writing a Sql command. I am pretty new at sql so everything is a little confusing.
The problem:
For each instructor list his / her name and the number of students he / she mentors

There are three tables:

- Person with the Names and ID
- Instructor with Instructor ID which references ID
- Student with StudentID and MentorID which references ID

I tried:

```
select distinct p.Name,count(d.MentorID) 
from Person p, Instructor e, Student d
where e.InstructorID = d.MentorID   
and p.ID = e.InstructorID;
```

But that only gives me one results instead a count per instructor.

Comment: Use `GROUP` and `HAVING`

Answer (score 1):

Build a group and then `count()` counts for every group and not the complete result.

```
select p.Name, count(d.MentorID) 
from Person p
join Instructor e on p.ID = e.InstructorID
join Student d on e.InstructorID = d.MentorID  
group by p.Name
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked beautifully and good explanation also!